# stored procedure sql syntax error

Tags: mysql

I've got 5 tables in database

```
ApartamentClass(idclass,descript)
Room(idroom,idclass,beds,isfree)
ItemPrice(iditem,idclass,description,price)
Client(idclient,fio)
Active(idcontract,idclient,idroom,days,price,idclass)
```

I need to create a stored procedure that check whether exists free room with certain class`(param1)` and number of beds `(param2)` and create renting contract for this room and client(fio)`(param3)` for several days `(param4)`.
The price depends on class of the room(higher class -> higher price for one bed and one day).

```
create procedure UserRequest(
    in param1 int,
    in param2 int,
    in param3 varchar(100),
    in param4 int
)
begin   
    declare iroom int default 0;
    select idroom into iroom from room
    where beds = param2 and idclass = param1 and isfree = 0
    limit 1;


    if not (iroom=0) then
        update room set isfree = 1
        where idroom = iroom;
    end if;


    declare iclient int default 0;
    select idclient into iclient from client
    where fio = param3
    limit 1;


    declare bedprice decimal default 0.0;
    select (param2 * price) into bedprice from itemprice
    where description = "bed" and idclass = param1;

    declare dayprice decimal default 0.0;
    select (param4 * price) into dayprice from itemprice
    where description = "day" and idclass = param1;

    declare price decimal default 0.0;
    set price = bedprice + dayprice;


    insert into active(idclient,idroom,days,price,idclass)
    values(iclient,iroom,param4,price,param1);
end
```

But I always get SQL syntax error. I can't get where the problem is.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare iclient int default 0;
        select idclient into iclient from client
        wh' at line 20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the DECLARE statements must be at the beginning of the BEGIN... END block as stated in the MySQL documentation here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

So, you might want to try the following code:

```
create procedure UserRequest(
    in param1 int,
    in param2 int,
    in param3 varchar(100),
    in param4 int
)
begin   
    declare iroom int default 0;
    declare iclient int default 0;
    declare bedprice decimal default 0.0;
    declare dayprice decimal default 0.0;
    declare price decimal default 0.0;

    select idroom into iroom from room
    where beds = param2 and idclass = param1 and isfree = 0
    limit 1;


    if not (iroom=0) then
        update room set isfree = 1
        where idroom = iroom;
    end if;


    select idclient into iclient from client
    where fio = param3
    limit 1;

    select (param2 * price) into bedprice from itemprice
    where description = "bed" and idclass = param1;

    select (param4 * price) into dayprice from itemprice
    where description = "day" and idclass = param1;

    set price = bedprice + dayprice;


    insert into active(idclient,idroom,days,price,idclass)
    values(iclient,iroom,param4,price,param1);
end
```

Comment: Yes it works! But why position of `declare` does have matter in MySQL?